# Adding a bundled product to a cart using SOAP V2

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, soap, shopping-cart, bundled-product

We're running a magento enterprise v1.13 store and are currently creating a mobile app for it using SOAP v2.

When trying to add a bundled product to a cart using `shoppingCartProductAdd` using this request:

```
  <urn:shoppingCartProductAddRequestParam>
     <sessionId>986d4ea8336a286448c443da7e8547a6</sessionId>
     <quoteId>100</quoteId>
     <productsData>
        <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
        <complexObjectArray>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <product_id>6426</product_id>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <sku></sku>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <qty>1</qty>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <options>
              <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->

           </options>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <bundle_option>
              <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->

           </bundle_option>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <bundle_option_qty>
              <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->

           </bundle_option_qty>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <links>

           </links>
        </complexObjectArray>
     </productsData>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <store>2</store>
  </urn:shoppingCartProductAddRequestParam>
```

we get the error:

```
  <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
     <faultcode>1022</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Please select options for product.</faultstring>
  </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```

Any idea where to get those options from? `catalogProductInfo` returns `has_option` as true but I can't find those options anywhere!

Comment: Please post the code you are using to add the product to the cart.

Comment: I'm currently trying to add it via SoapUI. I'll add the request in the original post.